# бесконечный цикл angular

Tags: angular

token.interceptor.ts:

```
  this.subscription=  this.auth.refreshToken().subscribe(data => {
                  console.log(data);
                  return;
                });
```

AuthService.ts:

```
refreshToken() {
    let user: User = this.currentUserValue;    
      const refreshToken = user.jwt.refreshToken;
      const param = {
        "refreshToken": refreshToken
    };
    return this.http.post<ApiResult<JWT>>('/api/authenticate/refreshaccesstoken', param).pipe(map(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      let user = new User();
      user.jwt = resp.data;
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUserSubject.next(user);     
        return resp;
      }));
  }
```

Почему происходит бесконечный цикл?

Comment: вопрос непонятен, постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы :)

Comment: где тут вообще цикл?

Comment: задача такая: если у пользователи срок токена закончился во время запроса, нужно у апи запросить новый токен с помощью refreshToken. я сделал методы которые указал, но оно у меня не правильно работает, получается бесконечные запросы в апи, но console.log(); не выводит после subscribe

Comment: @АнуарТемирбулат прежде чем делать реализовывать перехватчики - почитайте документацию,  я думаю у вас останется меньше вопросов :)

Comment: @Эникейщик если перехватчик не возвращает поток - то получается бесконечный цикл